# TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable, Webpage Automation

Tags: python, pandas, automation, webdriver, sendkeys

How can I input data extracted from excel into a specific webpage text box. See code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Importing Excel data into the terminal for WIP Labels
#wips = pd.read_excel('/Users/juliobermudez/desktop/WipExample.xlsx')
#hi = wips.iloc[1, 1]


#Are these elements? I don't know.
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/juliobermudez/desktop/WIP/chromedriver')
keyboard = Controller ()

#Pull up the Plex Website
browser.get('website')

#Log in into Plex using username and passoword
username = browser.find_element_by_id('txtUserID')
username.send_keys('username')
password = browser.find_element_by_id('txtPassword')
password.send_keys('password')
company = browser.find_element_by_id('txtCompanyCode')
company.send_keys('companyname')
elem = browser.find_element_by_id('btnLogin')
elem.click()

#Wait 3 Secs
time.sleep(5)

#Navigate to the Add Inventory Module
keyboard.press('2')
keyboard.release('2')
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.press('1')
keyboard.release('1')
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.press('5')
keyboard.release('5')

#Import Excel Data
wips = pd.read_excel('/Users/juliobermudez/desktop/WipExample.xlsx', sheet_name=0, )
number = (wips.iloc[3,1])

#Begin the Automation of WIPs !
time.sleep(3)
keyboard.press(Key.tab)
keyboard.release(Key.tab)
keyboard.type(number)
```

After running the code I get the following error: TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable

I don't know what it means or how to fix it. I've tried other means but, I seem to be stuck in this.

Comment: Could you add to which line of code (which number) the error refers? It basically means that you can not iterate over an integer. An int is just a singular number unlike a list that would be iterable

Comment: @bjorn the last one, keyboard.type(number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html#reference) of pynput:

```
Controller.type(string)[source]
Types a string.

This method will send all key presses and releases necessary to type all characters in the string.

Parameters: string (str) – The string to type.
```

.type expects a string, so you can do:

```
keyboard.type(str(number))
```

In the last line and it should work

Comment: my guy this works ! thank you. To give you some background i'm doing to automate a task at work, which takes a lot of time. So, now I basically have to create a loop in order to do this for multiple lines of data. You're the man !

Comment: I'm happy to help! Can you consider accepting the answer? @jthesimple

Comment: answer accepted, I'm new to this programming stuff and stackoverflow, but you should be good to go. PS this is my first project

Comment: You have any doubts, you can always ask at StackOverflow, the community here is very receptive @jthesimple